# Many to many on the same table with additional columns

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, many-to-many

**Message POCO:**

```
[Table("Message")]
public class Message
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Int64 SenderID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Int64 ReceiverID { get; set; }

    public String Body { get; set; }

}
```

THE `SenderID` and `ReceiverID` are foreign keys on `UserID` in `User` table

**User POCO:**

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**I need a many-to-many relationship:** `Icollection<Message> Messages` property in `User` POCO and `User Sender`, `User Receiver` properties in `Message` POCO.
How I must do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Message POCO:**

```
[Table("Message")]
public class Message
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Sender")]
    public Int64 SenderID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Receiver")]
    public Int64 ReceiverID { get; set; }

    public String Body { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("SentMessages")]
    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ReceivedMessages")]
    public virtual User Receiver { get; set; }
}
```

**User POCO:**

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Message> SentMessages { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Message> ReceivedMessages { get; set; }
}
```